# Fade in images after loading with preloader icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I have thumbnail grid build and i would like to achieve a fade in of the images after they have been loaded with a image placeholder and preloader on top. I have a example from a website that uses the same principal of loading the images (look at the grey background and circle loader on top):

[--> See website example](http://sagmeisterwalsh.com/work)

[--> Here my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pallum/f8wgfwtt/5/) (with the script that i'm trying to adjust to my situation)

**This is my thumbnail grid stucture:**

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">

    <div class="grid-group compact-group">

        <div class="grid-item size-xs compact-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-800-570-2.jpg">
                <div class="caption">Project untitled</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item size-xs compact-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-800-570-4.jpg">
                <div class="caption">Project untitled</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item size-xs compact-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-800-570-7.jpg">
                <div class="caption">Project untitled</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item size-xs compact-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-800-570-5.jpg">
                <div class="caption">Project untitled</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- grid-group -->
</div>
<!-- grid-wrapper -->
```

Comment: try in javascript with requireJS

Comment: Check in https://api.jquery.com/load-event/, you can prehaps use that event?

Comment: @fro yes well, but how is the question i can't get to work? In my fiddle there is a javascript code that the example website uses i thought it would be easy to adjust it to my situation.